# Perl Net::Telnet different credential

Tags: perl, telnet

I am trying a script to login to multiple devices. Few device accept some other credential and few others accept something else.

Prepared script to tell if first credential not accepted than tried other one.

Here is code:

```
use Net::Telnet;
use warnings;

my @op="";

my $session = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10,Input_log =>\*STDOUT,Errmode=>   'return');
$session->open('172.16.76.159');


my $code1 = q/
$session->login('gmahesh','abcd');
/;

my $result1 = eval($code1);


unless ($result1){

my $code2 = q/
$session->login('rjil','xyz');

/;
}

$session->cmd('term len 0');
@op=$session->cmd('sh isis neighbor');
```

Now the router (172.16.76.159) is configured with second credential (rjil one) but output of login not even trying this credential.

User Access Verification

```
 Username: gmahesh
 Password:

 % Authentication failed

 Username: term len 0   <<< It is not trying rjil username
 Password:
```